# Queue with using array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

In our midterm exam teacher asked us to do this question below:
Write a generic Queue class which uses an array(not a link list) as a memory storage. It should support generic type parameter and array resizing (both growing and shrinking), but it doesn't have to support iterators.Hints:Queue is a FIFO data structure ; the API for a queue contains **enqueue, dequeue,size and isEmpty** methods in addition to the constructor; you don't have to implement toString.

I tried to write this code and here's what I wrote. But I don't know how should I check this code. Is it correct or how can I check it?

```
 public class Queue<T> {
 public T[] array;
 public int N;

 public boolean isEmpty() {
  return N == 0;
}

 public int size() {
  return N;
}

public void resize(int max) {
  T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[max];
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     temp[i] = array[i];
   }
   array = temp;
 }

public void enqueue(T item) {
  if (isEmpty()) {
  array[0] = item;
   N++;
 } else if (N == array.length) {
   resize(array.length * 2);
   array[N] = item;
   N++;
} else {
  array[N] = item;
  N++;
 }
}

 public T dequeue() {
  T value = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      array[i - 1] = array[i];
  }
     array[--N] = null;
     return value;
 }
}
```

Comment: To check, write tests. A test may be trying to fill the queue such that it will resize, empty the queue, verify that everything pushed in it can be extracted from, etc.

Comment: Write a unit test for it. Enque a single element, assert that it contains what is expected. Enqueue a few elements, assert. Dequeue from empty, assert that exception is thrown. Enqueue a few, then dequeue, assert that elements are correct and in expected order. Finally, write a test that checks for resizing. That should cover it, no?

Comment: I recommend a tutorial on unit testing, e.g. [this one over at `vogella.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+unit+testing+tutorial&oq=java+unit+testing+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l8.3782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). --- A remark I would just use an `Object[]` instead of a `T[]`. This is how [`ArrayList` (`github.com`)](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L136) does things. Mixing arrays and generics is always a pain since arrays are covariant and retained, while generics are invariant and erased

Comment: One more hint: `System.arrayCopy` is your friend... https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)

Comment: *"both growing and shrinking"*: you didn't do the shrinking part.

Comment: I tried to do shrinking in dequeue func. with array[--N]=null; @trincot

Comment: But is that what is intended? I thought shrinking would mean the allocated array would shrink to half its size. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Hi senasimsek, your code produce a null pointer exception as long the array variable is never instantiated, at least not in the code you posted. Gonna make some fixes here and there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code with my revisions. I preserved your general approach I just made some fixes.

Of course other optimizations are possible but I'll leave them to you ;)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Queue<T> {
    //never expose directly as public internal variables of your classes. So they should be private
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private T[] array;
    private int n;

    //these 2 variables define the expansion and reducing policy so that may be changed dynamically
    private final float policyToExpand = 3.0f/4.0f;
    private final float policyToReduce = 1.0f/4.0f;

//you didn't implement the constructor of your class that was required. This should do the work.
//Just mind that the 4 it's the initial capacity of the array.
public Queue(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 4);
    this.n = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return n == 0;
}

public int size() {
    return n;
}

//cleaned a bit enqueue and dequeue method and extrapolating the logic for resize.
public void enqueue(T item) {
    array[n] = item;
    n++;
    if(expansionIsNeeded()) performResizeExpanding();
}

public T dequeue() {
    T value = array[0];
    slideBackArray();
    n--;
    if(reduceIsNeeded()) performResizeReducing();
    return value;
}


//logic for sliding back items when dequeueing
private void slideBackArray() {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
    }
    array[n] = null;
}


//these 2 methods take care of triggering resize
private boolean expansionIsNeeded() {
    float currentFilling = (float) n / array.length;
    return currentFilling >= policyToExpand;
}
private boolean reduceIsNeeded() {
    float currentFilling = (float) n / array.length;
    return currentFilling <= policyToReduce;
}

//these 2 instead perform the actual resize
private void performResizeExpanding() {
    T[] tempArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, this.array.length*2);
    System.arraycopy(this.array, 0, tempArray, 0, n);
    this.array = tempArray;
}

private void performResizeReducing() {
    T[] tempArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, this.array.length/2);
    System.arraycopy(this.array, 0, tempArray, 0, n);
    this.array = tempArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The first `enqueue` call will already produce an Null Pointer Exception. A minimal test would have revealed this. Your `array` is not initialised and so access to `array.length` or `array[0]` or similar will trigger a NPE. You need to initialise the array upon construction.
- `array.length * 2` will not change the array size when it is 0, it is probably best to initialise your array with a size of at least 1, and never allow it to be come less.
- Code that shrinks the array is lacking.
- `dequeue` should not have to move every element every time you call it. Typically, an array-based queue keeps track of the *start* of the data and the *end*, so that the used part of the array does not necessarily have to start at index 0. Instead of an `N` member, define `start` and `end` members.

Here is a possible adjustment of your class:

```
public class Queue<T> {
    private T[] array;
    private int start, end; // Instead of N, so to gain efficiency in dequeue
    
    Queue() {
        array = (T[]) new Object[1]; // Initialise!
    }
     
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return start == end;
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return (end + array.length - start) % array.length;
    }
     
    public void resize(int max) {
        T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[max];
        if (end > start) {
            end -= start;
            System.arraycopy(array, start, temp, 0, end);
            start = 0;
            end %= max;
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, end);
            int size = array.length - start;
            System.arraycopy(array, start, temp, max - size, size);
            start = max - size;
        }
        array = temp;
    }
    
    public void enqueue(T item) {
        array[end] = item;
        end = (end + 1) % array.length;
        if (start == end) {
            resize(array.length * 2);
        }
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        if (array.length > 1 && size() <= array.length / 2) {
            resize(array.length / 2); // Shrink
        }
        T value = array[start];
        array[start] = null;
        start = (start + 1) % array.length;
        return value;
    }
}
```